# Load functions on specifc days and time

Tags: settimeout, getdate

I've got some functions to run on different days, starting always at a certain time. To make it more clear:

function a, function b, function c

monday: function a; 
tuesday: function a; 
thursday: function b; 
wednesday: function c; 
... and so on

they all should start at 10am

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use javascript then you can do this.

```
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date();  
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Sunday";
    weekday[1] = "Monday";
    weekday[2] = "Tuesday";
    weekday[3] = "Wednesday";
    weekday[4] = "Thursday";
    weekday[5] = "Friday";
    weekday[6] = "Saturday";
    var t = d.getHours(); //this is return time

    var n = weekday[d.getDay()]; //this will return day
    If(n== "monday" && t == 10){
     //do something here
    }

}
```